# Is it possible to have an input from a form in a html template be added to the url in a django project?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-forms

In the sidebar of my homepage, there is a search box where a user is meant to be able to type in the name of an entry and be taken to that page. So for example, if they type in `css` they would be taken to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/css` where the value inputted is appended to the url. (The home page url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/`.)

When I use the `get` method in the form it ends up searching up `/wiki/?q=css` instead of just having `/css` at the end of the url. However, when I use the `post` method in my form the url remains at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/` with no additional url at the end.

How do I append an input to the end of a url?

HTML:

```
<h2>Wiki</h2>
<form action="/wiki/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
from tokenize import Name
from unicodedata import name
from django.urls import path

from django.http import HttpResponse

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path('hello/', views.hello, name='hello'),
    path('<str:name>', views.entry, name='entry'),
    path('new/', views.new, name='new'),
    path('random/', views.randomEntry, name='random')
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import forms
import random

from . import util


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })


def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, world')


def entry(request, name):
    return HttpResponse(util.get_entry(name))


def search(name):
    value = util.get_entry(name)
    if value != None:
        return value


class searchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(label='Search Encyclopedia')
    # this was not used as I do not know if it would be useful


def new(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/new.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })


def randomEntry(request):
    list = []
    for i in util.list_entries():
        list.append(i)
    num = random.randint(0, len(list)-1)
    page = list[num]
    return render(request, f"entries/layout.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })
```

util.py (I don't know if this is useful but it could be used):

```
import re
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage


def list_entries():
    """
    Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
    """
    _, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))


def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))


def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your input form post to a new view that retrieves the field value and then redirects to a your wiki entry based on that value

html

```
<h2>Wiki</h2>
<form action="{% url 'wiki-lookup' %}" method="post">
```

views.py

```
def wiki-lookup(request):
    #first we get the posted q term, or return 'notfound' if the form fails to provide a value
    term = request.POST.get('q', 'notfound')
    #....test term for validity here as appropriate
    #next redirect to 'entry' passing the term as the name value for that URL
    return redirect('entry', name = term)
```

urls.py

```
...
path('wiki-lookup/', views.wiki-lookup, name='wiki-lookup'),
```

Django is actually quite neat in that views don't have to be actual pages - they can just do some work to determine which page the user should actually end up at.

Comment: To test it for validity, would I run a search to see if the search term is in the list of `entries`?  And if it is, then I would redirect the user, right?

Comment: That would be one thing.  Depending on your naming system you might also want to strip spaces or non- alphabetic characters, lower capital letters or check for common misspellings etc.

Comment: Okay thank you. But also how would I do this without having to go to a different url? Would I be able to do the same thing while having the user be directed to `wiki/entry` instead of `wiki-lookup`?

Comment: The user will never actually see wiki-lookup as a separate page because that view doesn't return a rendered page. Instead, it returns a redirect that takes the user to wiki/searchterm, and that's how it will look in their browser. The redirect happens in the backend. /wiki-lookup just does the job of converting the searchterm into part of a new url. You could conceivably do all of this in one view, but you would need the view to work both with and without <str:name> which gets fiddly because without <str:name> is identical to the URL for your index page.

Comment: Thanl you it worked all I had to change was the `form action` as I changed it to `form action: {% url 'wki-lookup' %}` and that worked as when it was `wiki-lookup/`  it actually tried to render a page with `wiki-lookup/` as its url but it did not exist so instead I linked the url.

Comment: `form action: {% url 'wiki-lookup' %}` is better as it will handle any later url changes.  Glad you got it working!