# How do I append an input from a form in a html template to a url?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a search bar on my homepage (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/`) where I want users to be able to search for entries and be shown the entry through the url. So, if the user searched for `css` in the search bar, they would be redirected to `/wiki/css` (`/wiki` needs to be kept the same).  When something is searched the url stays the same, so it is not redirected or might have been redirected to the same page.

How do I append the search term to the url without using a different url?

HTML:

```
<h2>Wiki</h2>
<form action="/wiki/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<str:name>', views.wiki_lookup, name='wiki-lookup'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse

def wiki_lookup(request):
    term = request.POST.get('q', 'notfound')
    return redirect('entry', name=term)
```

Comment: I found the answer at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72959098/is-it-possible-to-have-an-input-from-a-form-in-a-html-template-be-added-to-the-u/72959450#72959450)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for redirect, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect there are three ways to use redirect.

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(...)
return redirect(obj)
```

or

```
return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

or

```
return redirect('/some/url/')
```

You are using the second, where 'entry' is expected to be the name of another view (defined in views.py and included in urls.py).  Something like

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('wiki/', views.wiki_lookup, name='wiki-lookup'),
    path('wiki/<slug:term>/', views.EntryDetailView.as_view(), name='entry'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Entry
```

I have used a class based view, but you could use a view function that looked up the Entry if you prefer.

Comment: How would I link my HTML form to this url?